# Can't import SASS & SCSS simultaneously in React Webpack

Tags: sass, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

As mentioned in the title, I cannot import both scss and sass files simultaneously.

```
import Style from '../styles/app.scss'
```

Then all the partials and dependencies must be .scss or it won't work. If I try to import a sass partial, it wouldn't work. Some dependencies have their base file in scss and the variables, etc in sass.

An example is font-awesome. Their base file is font-awesome.scss and it imports _variables.sass, etc from it.

Here's my webpack config file.

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: "style!css!sass?indentedSyntax"
    }, {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
      loaders: [
        'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
        'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
      ]  
    }, { 
      test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff"
    }, { 
      test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
      loader: "file-loader" 
    }, {
      test: /\.sass$/,
      // Passing indentedSyntax query param to node-sass
      loader: "style!css!sass?indentedSyntax"
    }]
  },
```

I have sass-loader and node-sass modules. This is the error being shown. It's trying to load bourbon as a sass.

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader?indentedSyntax!./app/styles/app.scss
Module build failed:
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
       ^
      File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon/bourbon.sass
      in /Users/Akhil/Sites/todoo/react/app/styles/app.scss (line 1, column 9)
 @ ./app/styles/app.scss 4:14-135 13:2-17:4 14:20-141
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you need to install bourbon and/or fix include pathing?

Comment: Seems like it works If I give the extension of the filename explicity. Like so:

@import "bourbon/bourbon.scss"